# Is it possible to have an event bus in C?

Tags: c, embed

I need to create a module (composed by multiple components) for various embedded system (runnning under linux,android, windows ce). And I am still in the design phase : 
  - I have decided to code my component in C in order to favor portability and efficiency :  every other vendors could then incorporate my component in their application on linux, android or windows CE. 
  - I also want to propose to decouple my components from their usage by using a kind of event bus.
 But it is possible to use a portable event bus in pure C  ? Or the best I could offer is a registration of callback functions ?

Comment: C does no have any event bus or other such container.   I can see no alternative to the user  providing function pointers to essential services and/or OS interfaces for queue management, e.g. mutex, semaphore etc.

Comment: The C language has no such standard feature, but there are plenty of them available--DBUS, for example.

Comment: I haven't find if dbus is available on Android... Also, could I rely on this feature if I am not responsible for the plateform : I have only a component (dll,so) that should be embed in third party application....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a message broker.  I use Apache's Active MQ (http://activemq.apache.org/) in many of my c services.  If you want something light weight, try Mosquitto (https://mosquitto.org/)

Comment: My module should be thought like a SDK to be incorporated in some others vendors application : alas I could not rely on a proper soft broker.